# 403 error while downloading file using perl script

Tags: perl

I am new to perl scripting and am trying to write a program to download a tar file from an apache server with the below code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = "http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-good/gst-plugins-good-1.2.2.tar.xz";
my $file ="gst-plugins-good-1.2.2.tar.xz";
my $rc = getst

ore($url, $file) ;
print($rc);
```

But I am getting a `403 error`. I don't know why. I tried many thing like sending request with user agent. But it's not working. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: My fault. Env proxy was refusing the connection. I did unset of http_proxy of env. Now error 500. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are extra spaces between "getst" and "ore"...:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = "http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-good/gst-plugins-good-1.2.2.tar.xz";
my $file ="gst-plugins-good-1.2.2.tar.xz";
my $rc = getstore($url, $file);
print($rc);
```

Executing this code here returns 200 (OK) code...

Comment: my $url = "http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-good/gst-plugins-good-1.2.2.tar.xz"; 
is the url which contains the file. So, whats the point of appending $file?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought $url contained only the directory part, my mistake... Error 500 is probably a php syntax error... did you remove the extra newline between "getst" and "ore", I presume... :-)

Comment: Got the answer. Environment proxy was setting to some different proxy that was refusing the connection with 403 error. Changed that and its working fine now. Thanks a lot for your help.